# Unable to connect worker node to master using K3S

Tags: k3s

I am trying to setup a K3S cluster for learning purposes but I am having trouble connecting the master node with agents. I have looked several tutorials and discussions on this but I can't find a solution. I know I am probably missing something obvious (due to my lack of knowledge), but still help would be much appreciated.

I am using two AWS t2.micro instances with default configuration.

When ssh into the master and installed K3S using

```
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -s - --no-deploy traefik --write-kubeconfig-mode 644 --node-name k3s-master-01
```

with kubectl get nodes, I am able to see the master

```
NAME            STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION
k3s-master-01   Ready    control-plane,master   13s   v1.23.6+k3s1
```

So far it seems I am doing things right. From what I understand, I am supposed to configure the kubeconfig file. So, I accessed it by using

```
cat /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml
```

I copied the configuration file and the server info to match the private IP I took from AWS console, resulting in something like this

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: <lots_of_info>
    server: https://<master_private_IP>:6443
  name: default
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: default
    user: default
  name: default
current-context: default
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: default
  user:
    client-certificate-data: <my_certificate_data>
    client-key-data: <my_key_data>
```

Then, I ran `vi ~/.kube/config`, and there I pasted the kubeconfig file

Finally, I grabbed the token with `cat /var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/node-token`, ssh into the other machine and then run the following

```
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | K3S_NODE_NAME=k3s-worker-01 K3S_URL=https://<master_private_IP>:6443 K3S_TOKEN=<master_token> sh -
```

The output is

```
[INFO]  Finding release for channel stable
[INFO]  Using v1.23.6+k3s1 as release
[INFO]  Downloading hash https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/releases/download/v1.23.6+k3s1/sha256sum-amd64.txt
[INFO]  Downloading binary https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/releases/download/v1.23.6+k3s1/k3s
[INFO]  Verifying binary download
[INFO]  Installing k3s to /usr/local/bin/k3s
[INFO]  Skipping installation of SELinux RPM
[INFO]  Creating /usr/local/bin/kubectl symlink to k3s
[INFO]  Creating /usr/local/bin/crictl symlink to k3s
[INFO]  Creating /usr/local/bin/ctr symlink to k3s
[INFO]  Creating killall script /usr/local/bin/k3s-killall.sh
[INFO]  Creating uninstall script /usr/local/bin/k3s-agent-uninstall.sh
[INFO]  env: Creating environment file /etc/systemd/system/k3s-agent.service.env
[INFO]  systemd: Creating service file /etc/systemd/system/k3s-agent.service
[INFO]  systemd: Enabling k3s-agent unit
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/k3s-agent.service → /etc/systemd/system/k3s-agent.service.
[INFO]  systemd: Starting k3s-agent
```

By this output, it looks like I have created an agent. However, when I run kubectl get nodes in the master, I still get

```
NAME            STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION
k3s-master-01   Ready    control-plane,master   12m   v1.23.6+k3s1
```

What is the thing I was supposed to do in order to get the agent connected to the master? I am guess I am probably missing something simple, but I just can't seem to find the solution. I've read all the documentation but it is still not clear to me where I am making the mistake. I've tried saving the private master IP and token into the agent as environmental variables with export K3S_TOKEN=master_token and K3S_URL=master_private_IP and then simply running `curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -`  but I still can't see the worker nodes when running `kubectl get nodes`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It might be your VM instance firewall that prevents appropriate connection from your master to the worker node (and vice versa). Official rancher [documentation](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/installation-requirements/) advise to disable firewall for (**Red Hat/CentOS**) Enterprise Linux:

1. It is recommended to turn off firewalld:

```
systemctl disable firewalld --now
```

2. If enabled, it is required to disable nm-cloud-setup and reboot the node:

```
systemctl disable nm-cloud-setup.service nm-cloud-setup.timer reboot
```

If you are using **Ubuntu** on your VM's, there is a different firewall tool (ufw).
In my case, allowing 6443 and 443(not sure if required) port TCP connections worked fine.

1. Allow port 6443 and TCP connection in all of your cluster machines:

```
sudo ufw allow 6443/tcp
```

Then apply k3s installation script in your worker node(s):

```
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | K3S_NODE_NAME=k3s-worker-1 K3S_URL=https://<k3s-master-1 IP>:6443 K3S_TOKEN=<k3s-master-1 TOKEN> sh -
```

This should work. If not, you can try adding additional allow rule for 443 tcp port as well.

Comment: Hello, Slazak, thank you for the answer. I am using Ubuntu indeed. I've tried running all of the above commands. First I ran `systemctl disable firewalld --now` and `systemctl disable nm-cloud-setup.service nm-cloud-setup.timer reboot`, but I got that `Failed to disable unit: Unit file firewalld.service does not exist. ` and `Failed to disable unit: Unit file nm-cloud-setup.service does not exist`. I then tried allowing both 6443 and 443 port tcp connection in all machines, but I still can't see the nodes when running kubectl get nodes in master. Is there anything else I might be missing?

Comment: Additional comments. I am running everything in root user.

Comment: Did you do this on both, master and the worker instance? There might be other firewall rules already applied in the Ubuntu system iptables that prevents your worker to connect to master. If your VM's are behind network firewall, you can try disabling instance (VM) firewall completely. First type `sudo ufw disable`, then `sudo iptables -F`. Make sure you did it on both, master and the worker.

Comment: Hi @Slazak, I did try both on mater and worker. And now I have tried also disabling firewall completely with `sudo ufw disable` and `sudo iptables -F`. I still can't see agent node when running `kubectl get nodes` on master. Just out of curiosity, I ran kubectl get nodes on the agent node and got `The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`.

Comment: @pedrozuccolo, You will not be able to reach master instance from your worker nodes by default, that's why you see `The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused`. For your specific setup, it's hard to say why you cannot form your cluster, but did you repeat all the installation steps for K3s master and workers after removing firewall?

Comment: Hello @Slazak, sorry for the delay. I was finally able to form the cluster. I deleted all instances and began from scratch. The difference is that is started by disabling firewalls prior to following all of the steps. It is working now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A few options to check.

1. Check Journalctl for errors

> journalctl -u k3s-agent.service -n 300 -xn

2. If using RaspberryPi for a worker node, make sure you have

> cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_enable=memory cgroup_memory=1

as the very end of your /boot/cmdline.txt file. DO NOT PUT THIS VALUE ON A NEW LINE! Should just be appended to the end of the line.

3. If your master node(s) have self-signed certs, make sure you copy the master node's self signed cert to your worker node(s). In linux or raspberry pi copy cert to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates, then issue an

> sudo update-ca-certificates

on the worker node

4. Don't forget to reboot the worker node after you make these changes!

Hope this helps someone!